# Jest: test Intl.DateTimeFormat

Tags: javascript, jestjs, datetime-format

I would like to test a filter function I wrote which return a date formatted using Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', options):

```
// module "date.js"
export default function (dateISOString) {
    const options = {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit',
        timeZone: 'UTC'
    };
    let d = new Date(dateISOString);
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', options).format(d);
};
```

This is my test, using Jest:

```
import date from '@/filters/date';
describe('date', () => {
    it('should format the date into dd/mm/yyyy', () => {
        expect(date('2014-02-11')).toEqual('11/02/2014');
    });
});
```

but it fails with:

```
Expected value to equal:
  "11/02/2014"
Received:
  "02/11/2014"
```

Is it possible to test (or mock) the Intl API with Jest?
It looks like the problem is due to a different behaviour of the Impl API in the browser and in a Node environment.

Answer (score 18):

The only solution that I managed to find to this problem was to install [full-icu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/full-icu) which seemed to provide the right locales to node during the testing process.

That package is needed because node by default only ships with a limited set of locales, explained here: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/intl.html

With that package installed, the additional step that I had to take was to change my test command to use:

`"test": "NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu jest --config jest.config.js"`

I ran into this problem in a couple of different environments. When running the tests locally on Mac OS and also when running the tests inside a Docker container during CI.

Interestingly, I don't need to use the export when running the tests via WebStorm's Jest integration. It definitely seems like the behaviour of the Intl library is far from stable in node.

Comment: You may be able to skip installing full-icu if your OS already has it available . For example, on Mac OS, you likely have an icudt*.dat file in /usr/share/icu, so you can set your test script to `"NODE_ICU_DATA=/usr/share/icu jest ..."`.

Comment: @JasonRice That's the syntax for setting environment variables on Linux (bash) and similar. The React folks have a [nice summary](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-temporary-environment-variables-in-your-shell) of setting variables in other shells. Maybe try `"test": "set \"NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu\" && jest ..."`.

Comment: Thanks for the link but it's always nice to know how to do it for both environments especially when posting. I ended up just using the npm cross-env prepended to the command. That seems to work well and requires no additional config.

Comment: To make it work on both windows/linux I use cross-env package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env more info about how it works: https://www.basefactor.com/javascript-es6-intl-not-working-properly-when-running-jest-tests

Answer (score 10):

Just found a solution if you want to change the zone per test.

The benefit here is minimal change to the Intl object since we are just using the normal api to set a default

```
const timezoneMock = function(zone: string) {
    const DateTimeFormat = Intl.DateTimeFormat
    jest
    .spyOn(global.Intl, 'DateTimeFormat')
    .mockImplementation((locale, options) => new DateTimeFormat(locale, {...options, timeZone: zone}))
  }

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  })
```

and then

```
  describe('when Europe/London', () => {
    it('returns local time', () => {
      timezoneMock('Europe/London')
   //etc....
```

Comment: Genius!!! This is the best way to mock time zone in tests as far as I am concerned

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect, because it does not only change the timezone, but also overrides the timezone argument if it is passed explicitly to the DateTimeFormat. A correct solution would have `timeZone: options.timezone ?? zone`

Comment: Also, with this solution, the static method `supportedLocalesOf` of `DateTimeFormat` is not mocked. If your code uses it, it needs to be mocked too, with `Intl.DateTimeFormat.supportedLocalesOf = DateTimeFormat.supportedLocalesOf;`

Answer (score 3):

You can use polyfill, as described [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-intl)

```
import IntlPolyfill from 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/ru';

if (global.Intl) {
    Intl.NumberFormat = IntlPolyfill.NumberFormat;
    Intl.DateTimeFormat = IntlPolyfill.DateTimeFormat;
} else {
    global.Intl = IntlPolyfill;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me with Node 15 where `"test": "NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu jest --config jest.config.js"` didn't

Answer (score 2):

In **package.json** add the `intl` package

```
 "intl": "*",
```

In the **jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    moduleNameMapper: {
        Intl: '<rootDir>/node_modules/intl/'
    }
};
```

Then in **Date.spec.js**

```
 describe(`Date by locale`, () => {
     beforeAll(() => {  global.Intl = require('intl'); });
    // Add your tests here. 
    // Add a temporary console.log to verify the correct output
 }
```

Comment: Good but https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

These are all convoluted answers. The simplest is extending the prototype like so in jest. Modify any property or function with define property

```
Object.defineProperty(Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype, 'formatToParts', {
  value: () => ['day', 'month', 'year'].map((type) => ({ type })),
})
```