# Intl.NumberFormat behaves incorrectly in Jest unit test?

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, jestjs, number-formatting

The [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/NumberFormat) site says:

```
var number = 123456.789;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' })
.format(number));

// expected output: "123.456,79 €"
```

But in my Jest unit test, I get as output `€ 123,456.79` which is not correct for `fr-FR` locale according to me and Mozilla example.

I've tried to load polyfills and locale data, but it does not seem to resolve the issue

```
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/complete';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/fr';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/fr-FR';
import 'intl/dist/Intl.complete';
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with EUR!

Comment: do you found the solution?

Comment: @AralRoca I posted my own answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52410531/82609 but didn't try it

Answer (score 10):

A solution that worked for me is:

1. `npm i full-icu`
2. Run your test with `NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu jest`

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question.

I think this is because we have to provide locales / ICU data to node. Loading the polyfill afterward does not patch the Intl api that is already present in node.

Didn't test further but these links can be helpful:

[Jest: test Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052731/jest-test-intl-datetimeformat/50119588)
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/api/intl.md

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, Node >= 13 has full-icu support enabled by default:
https://nodejs.medium.com/node-js-12-to-lts-and-node-js-13-is-here-e28d6a4a2bd

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an inconsistency between node and browser behavior. I think polyfills might not have worked, because your node has support for `Intl`. And there is a check to avoid overriding the native implementation. Try using `IntlPolyfill`, it should be available. 
I also tried node 6.14.4, and got `€123,456.79` :D

Comment: Hi. Isn't using IntlPolyfill already what I'm trying to do or another package?

Comment: Yeah, no, it is the same package. It's another global that the package exports. It always exports IntlPolyfill, and if Intl is not defined, I will make an alias for Intl.

Answer (score 1):

Please check node version first before other trials, because my previous node version was v10.16.0, and I have updated to v12.12.3 which is working for me.

And also, please add this `currentDisplay: 'narrowSymbol'` in your number format object, something like this:

```
{Intl.NumberFormat('en-AU', { style: 'currency', currency: 'AUD', currencyDisplay: 'narrowSymbol' }).format(
          (amount)
        )}
```