# When running tests with Jest, how do I get Intl.NumberFormat to recognize nanosecond?

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I have some JavaScript code that uses [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) to format numbers. Specifically, I am using it with these options:

```
  const formatterOptions: Intl.NumberFormatOptions = {
    style: 'unit',
    unit: 'nanosecond',
  };
```

When I run this code in the browser, the formatting works. This make sense, because the Intl.NumberFormat [documentation](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#table-sanctioned-single-unit-identifiers) indicates that it can support nanoseconds.

When I run a unit test with Jest, I get this error:

```
RangeError: Invalid unit argument for Intl.NumberFormat() 'nanosecond'
```

--

It seems like the code running in the Jest environment is not aware of 'nanosecond'.

I found [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52329629/intl-numberformat-behaves-incorrectly-in-jest-unit-test) that suggested that installing `full-icu` might fix the Jest unit test.

However, [the `full-icu` project](https://github.com/nodejs/full-icu-npm) says this should no longer be necessary; `node` should have the `full-icu` data already.

I tried installing `full-icu` and still got the error.

I updated to the latest versions of jest (29+) and jest-environment-jsdom (29+) in case that would help. I still got the error.

Comment: did you try with `unit: 'decimals'` instead of `unit: 'nanosecond'` i mean you can turn the money on from time to decimals

Comment: @rnewed_user I have used `style: 'decimal'` to format a value, but in that case, the output won't be something like "X nanoseconds". Instead, it will be something like "X" without a unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Debugged with a co-worker, and we found that the culprit was the **version of node**.

Our project is using `node 18.4.2`. At this version, the tests do not pass. At `node 18.17.1` (highest version of 18), the tests do not pass. At `node 19.8.1` (highest version of 19), the tests do not pass. At `node 20.0.0`, the tests do pass!

We assume that node 20 includes the nanosecond data that is used by `Intl.NumberFormat`. We assume that this is the same data that is already shipped in the browser, and this is why the code works in the browser.