# javascript localeCompare return different value on browser as comparing to my local testing

Tags: javascript

I have the following code executed:

```
var eng = 'image'
var chinese = '影像'
console.log(eng.localeCompare(chinese),"zh-hant")
```

on my browser console, the result is `1`

But when I run npm test to execute the above code, the result is `-1`

My questions are:

1. What makes the code return different value?
2. How can I fix this unstable code?

Comment: What's the version of your node.js? `node --version`

Comment: I found that I have a really old version, which is `v12.14.0`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to compare english language with chinese one. So, I suggest, you should use [Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator) when needed. Most modern browsers are supporting it

Collator will sort in almost any language you can think of and has numerous options for customizing sorting by accent marks, capitalization, etc.

This [compare](https://dev.to/aumayeung/comparing-non-english-strings-with-javascript-collators-57bf) link can help you understand how to compare non-english strings in Javascript

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do have hard time dealing with lots of Chinese characters in our system which is usually used by Chinese language users..  I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

The one you run in a browser (say Chrome) has better i18n support. And when you run it with `npm test`, you are dealing with node.js, most likely a version prior to v13, with which only the locale data for en-US is available by default.

Meaning the option you passed to [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), in your case, `"zh-hant"`, silently falls back to `en-US`, leading to the different behavior in your question.

Source: [Browser compatibility MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#browser_compatibility)

#### The fix?

- The easy path
  Upgrade your node.js to a version later than v13. Then you have full ICU (locale) data available, meaning you will have the same result with the browser.
- The hard option:

  If the upgrade is not an option, you will need to do this the hard way. Here are some links to start:

  1. Here you can install full icu
     https://github.com/unicode-org/full-icu-npm
  2. Provide icu data at run time      https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/intl.html#intl_providing_icu_data_at_runtime

Comment: I found that I have a really old version, which is `v12.14.0`.. I thought I have upgraded my node js recently, but I forgot, thank you for your answer, I'll try to upgrade it and try the test again!

Comment: adding a link here bcz I came across an old question today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52329629/intl-numberformat-behaves-incorrectly-in-jest-unit-test

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052731/jest-test-intl-datetimeformat